# Use external fonts in android

Tags: android, fonts, android-widget

I want to use external fonts in my app. I have tried adding new `fonts` using `AssetManager` but it did not work. Below is my code:

```
Typeface face;

face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.otf");

textview.setTypeface(face);
```

but its not showing the text...

Please help me with this.

Comment: ..to be tidy you can have the fonts in assets/fonts folder and access  

    
    Typeface face;
    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/" +"font.otf");
    textview.setTypeface(face);

Answer (score 69, accepted):

AFAIK, Android does not support OpenType. Use a TrueType font instead.

---

**UPDATE:** Apparently OpenType is now supported, at least somewhat. It was not supported originally, so you will want to test your font thoroughly on whatever versions of Android your app will support.

Comment: so you are saying that i am in right direction..i just need to use ttf file instead of otf???

Comment: Yes. Given your code, you need your font to be in the root of your assets/ directory, but otherwise it should be fine with a compatible font.

Comment: The error message indicates some communications difficulty between your emulator and either adb or Eclipse -- it has nothing to do with fonts. Download http://commonsware.com/Android/Android-src-2_1.zip and you will find an Android project that shows loading a TrueType font. Also note that Android 1.6 now appears to let you load fonts from outside of the APK (e.g., one you download separately).

Comment: How to access the fonts from library project ?? it does not work

Comment: @Maxwell: I do not believe that a library project's assets are available to apps using the library.

Comment: I had created an android library project.I integrated it to another project.Now I cannot access the assets from the library project to my new app.

Comment: I`v had an issue with bold custom font visualization(letters seams with transparent inner areas) on some devices, so I`ve converted .otf to .ttf via http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf and that`s solved the issue

Comment: In my case, I have used external fonts ( .ttf ) files. this file is working on IOS but not in android. And that font name is BELL.ttf,  you can download it from online.

Answer (score 12):

In order to access our font easily, we need to bundle it with our application in a way that our code can subsequently load it. To do this, we create a Fonts folder in our assets direct

This may be your .xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DefaultFontText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Here is some text." />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CustomFontText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Here is some text.">
    </TextView>
```

Write following code in your .java class

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/BPreplay.otf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 9):

Android does support OTF (I'm not sure from which SDK version but it definitely works with 1.6), I was using a typewriter OTF font for a while but the rendering is nowhere near as accurate as with the TTF version I ended up using (via online font converter). The baseline was all over the place (some letters were a full 2 pixels higher than others), and on LDPI phones like the HTC Wildfire the problem is greatly magnified due to the larger pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. My font was not working in android either but I needed it to work. Using a font editor, I copied the characters from my font into the font that comes with the FontSampler example from Android-src-2_1. It worked perfectly.

While I will admit that my method was questionable from an intellectual property point of view, I didn't actually wind up using the original font, as all of the characters were replaced and all references to the old font where replaced as well. I had tried 'looking' at the way the two fonts were defined but making all the font variables match didn't work either. So in the ned, I used a skeleton of the original font as a template for the new font.

Answer (score 1):

android supports both otf and ttf formats, i experienced both of them.

```
tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TRAJANPRO-BOLD.OTF");
    tv3.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

this is the step i used for both english and local languages

Answer (score 1):

Use Fontinator it support booth OTF and TTF Fonts

It is an Android-Library make it easy, to use custom Fonts.

https://github.com/svendvd/Fontinator

Comment: It's pretty good, but changing 1000+ TVs to their own custom ones... not too handy