# How can make "special" style numbers

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I make "special" style numbers, for example, scores for a game for Android. How I can use them to appear in the program like as "normal" numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom fonts for your TextView:

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/BPreplay.otf";
 tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Read this: [custom fonts](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about having [your own font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426244/use-external-fonts-in-android)? One solution would be to create 10 images (0-9) and write some code to populate one ore more `ImageView` views with the correct images to display your score.