# Asynctask inside Adapterview class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to change fonts of listview items. Without AsyncTasc it takes too much time. Using AsyncTask activity with that listview emerges fast and then after instance application crashes. I know that I can't change UI from AsyncTasc directly.What could I use? Thanks in advance

```
import ru.ayratbadykov.feedhandler.FEED;
import ru.ayratbadykov.feedhandler.RssMessage;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private FEED _data;
    Context _c;

    CustomAdapter(FEED data, Context c) {
        _data = data;
        _c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("here","here");
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) _c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);
        }

        TextView fromView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView subView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView View = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        RssMessage msg = _data.getMessages().get(position);
        new Font().execute(fromView,subView,View);





        fromView.setText(msg.getTitle());
        subView.setText(msg.getPUBDATE());
        View.setText(_data.getTitle());

        return v;
    }
    public class Font extends AsyncTask<TextView, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(TextView... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String fontPath = "fonts/Qlassik_TB.ttf";
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(_c.getAssets(), fontPath);
            params[0].setTypeface(tf);
            fontPath="fonts/damase.ttf";

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(_c.getAssets(), fontPath);
            params[1].setTypeface(tf);

            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(_c.getAssets(), fontPath);
            params[3].setTypeface(tf);
            return true;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.getMessages().size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.getMessages().get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
}
```

log

```
05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at ru.ayratbadykov.rssunion.CustomAdapter$Font$1.<init>(CustomAdapter.java:63)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at ru.ayratbadykov.rssunion.CustomAdapter$Font.doInBackground(CustomAdapter.java:63)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at ru.ayratbadykov.rssunion.CustomAdapter$Font.doInBackground(CustomAdapter.java:1)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    05-31 22:32:27.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2803):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: you are updating ui on the background thread. use runonuithread for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `UI` in `AsyncTask` just not from `doInBackground()`. But any other methods are fine. And since it is an inner class of your `Adapter` class which holds a reference to the `Context` then it is fine to do. Just move the code that uses `Context` or needs to update the `UI` to any other method.

For example, you could return an `ArrayList` of the `params` to `onPostExecute()` and update there or you could use `publishProgress()` and update them in `onProgressUpdate()`

[onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)

[onProogressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)

So also has a lot of good examples of using each

Comment: Don't forget onPreExecute() ;)

Comment: @Jarvis right, that's why I usually say any but `doInBackground()` but normally point out those two as it seems in my experience they are used more, at least in this type of situation. But I should probably start explicitly adding a comment about `onPreExecute()` because that isn't the first time I've had it pointed out. Thanks! :)

Comment: You are welcome, I have added a response for try to explain an asyntack

Comment: @Jarvis , your advice works but listview became very sluggish

Comment: I decided to use only only one font

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask allows you both to start a long process and access UI via the UIThread methods:

- onPreExecute(): to update the UI before the start of your treatment (the thread in doInBackground)
- onProgressUpdate(): to refresh UI during treatment
- onPostExecute(): to update UI at the end process.

**You have everything you need to do if you understand the operation of an Asynctask**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update ui on the background thread. doInBackground is invoked on the background thread. You should update ui on the ui thread.

You are trying to update textview in doInBackground. Use runOnUiThread if you need to update ui inside doInBackground().

I am also not sure why you require a asynctask for what you are doing.

```
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

          @Override
          public void run(){
            //update ui here
          }
       });
```

onPreExecute(),onPostExecute(Result), are invoked on the ui thread. So you can update ui here.

onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.

The result of doInbackground() computation is a parameter to onPostExecute(Result) so return the result in doinBackground() and show your toast in onPostExecute(Result)

For clarity check the link below under the topic The 4 steps.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can also use a handler for this purpose.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

Conisder solution not to create font from asset for every field.
Make static method returning Typeface, for example.
I'm setting fonts for list elements with no performance problems in UI thread.

for example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

static Typeface mFont = YourClass.getDefaultTypeFace();

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   TextView tv;
   ... 
   tv.setTypeface(mFont);
   ...
  }
}
```

Also, there are some issues with memory allocation for font assets, don't create multiply instances of Typeface. Check this, works perfect for me:
[To use or not to use Custom Fonts on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731845/to-use-or-not-to-use-custom-fonts-on-android/13768910#13768910)