# What font file types does Android support?

Tags: android, fonts

What font file types does Android support (for use with Typeface.createFromAsset, for instance)?

I can't seem to find a **list in the documentation.** I can see TTF gets mentioned in some tutorials and someone on here hinted that OTF is also supported now but is there a comprehensive list that shows what font file types are supported by the different API levels?

Many thanks.

EDIT: to be specific: can someone show me where it mentions font compatibility and supported font types in the docs - if there is anything there?

Comment: Some things still aren't officially documented except in the source code, which is (mostly) open. My guess is that this falls under that category, but it's difficult for me to prove that something *doesn't* exist :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android docs doesn't specify the fonts that it supports.When Android dislikes a custom font, rather than raising an Exception, it seems to substitute Droid Sans ("sans").

Comment: it raises an exception ..and then substitute with sans

Answer (score 23):

http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/18/fun-with-fonts/

[Use external fonts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426244/use-external-fonts-in-android)

TTF is always been supported.  OTF was later added at least in 1.6 and later, but partially.  Some TTF fonts Android doesn't like.

Comment: but is there any documentation on this? That's really what I'm after - I don't really need a tutorial on how to use them but thanks.

Comment: @chubbsondubs : Does android support dfont ttf families?

Comment: I doubt it.  dfont isn't ttf but you can convert it using this method: http://www.ehow.com/how_6192479_convert-dfont-ttf.html