# RuntimeException when trying to load font?

Tags: android, fonts

I'm making my first Android application and I want to add a custom font for a certain TextView. So I read about Typeface declaration and other people problem in some of the topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051915/how-to-install-custom-font-in-android-device) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051915/how-to-install-custom-font-in-android-device) . I create my own folder Fonts in assets and adding my font.tff there. Here is some code that I have just wrote:

```
textField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.threeMinutesTimer);
Typeface face;
face = createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/GAELLEnumber8.tff");
textField.setTypeface(face);
```

When I start my application I'm receiving an RuntimeException : native typeface cannot be made. Help.

Comment: **tff**? don't you mean **ttf** (TrueType Font)? Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8760782/2649012

Comment: Fonts dir is exist in your asset folder ?

Comment: wrong spelled....must be ttf, not tff. I think that´s the reason why..

Comment: Oh God, Thank you @Der Golem, sometimes the mistakes are so... Nevermind.

Comment: By the way, your "here" and "here" links are pointing to the same question