# Change TextView font which is not in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, listview, textview, typeface

I have ListView. It contains 3 TextView not from activity_main.xml.

```
   cursor = myDatabase.getJoinedInfo(etSearch.getText().toString().trim());

        String[] columns = new String[] { "re_value", "g_value", "ke_value" };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvHiragana, R.id.tvMeaning, R.id.tvKanji };

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.wordonlist,
                cursor, columns, to, 0);

        // Assign adapter to ListView

        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

How to change font of TextViews inside ListView?

```
final Typeface mFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/himaji.otf");
    LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.wordonlist, null, false);
    tvHiragana=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHiragana);
    tvHiragana.setTypeface(mFont);
```

This code could not change TextView's font. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: So `wordonlist.xml` is the list item layout file...correct?

Comment: To use a font stored in `assets`, you'll need to write a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can style your `TextViews` in xml (e.g. the row layout), as outlined in the [styles and themes article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

If you need to programmatically change the font (e.g. only for some instances, or using parameters not known at compile-time), you could create an anonymous subclass (or a regular subclass) of `SimpleCursorAdapter` which applies the changes in the adapter's `getView` method. For that, see a [slightly related answer to text color changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563698/how-to-change-text-color-of-simple-list-item). Your code inflates the layout (thus creating a new `View` instance), and changes that *single* instance, not the instances added to your list.

Answer (score 0):

OpenType Font is now supported
Use TrueType Font

[Font Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426244/use-external-fonts-in-android?lq=1)