# Android app shows incomplete text and incorrect font

Tags: android, android-layout

The screenshot below shows an issue of my app. The issue only happened once and is hard to reproduce. The app runs on the Galaxy S5 and the OS is Android 4.4.2.

[image: Incorrect Case]

As a comparison, the normal screenshot looks like below screenshot:

[image: Correct Case]

You can see parts of words are cut off but all the images are displayed properly like the cloud icon and the map icon.

The "weather and time" part is a RelativeLayout. And the 3 buttons on the bottom is also a RelativeLayout included in the parent layout which is the same parent of the "weather and time".

The app has several custom TextViews that extends the system TextView. And in custom TextView I used custom font. All the text are using the custom font. The font file is in otf.

The "weather part" used custom TextView and the text below the button icon used custom views as well.

I used the original ImageView to show images.

This is so weird and I can't figure out what was wrong with my app. Does that mean I need to do something specific to make my app compatible with Galaxy S5 or the latest phones?
Can somebody tell me what's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Forget my words hehe, if only happened once... I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Although Fonts with ***otf*** format can be used , but You should prefer ***ttf*** format , try converting it and let us know if that solved your issue , or if further investigation is required ;)

Also you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1430320) from which you may infer that this could be the problem of the chosen font or font format.

Enjoy!