# Custom font on NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, fonts, navigation-drawer, typeface, drawer

I'm trying to change the font on my navigationdrawer, I'm using a custom xml file with the adapter so I can change successfully the color and background of each element within the ListView, nevertheless I can't change the Typeface, AndroidStudio is giving me a *null object reference* so, I think it hasn't found the textview. My code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    TextView lbl = (TextView) mDrawerListView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Jaapokki-Regular.otf");
    lbl.setTypeface(tf);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            R.layout.fragment_main,
            R.id.section_label,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    "Acerca de...",
            }));

    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I doubt android doesn't supports OpenType fonts. Try using TrueType fonts instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426244/use-external-fonts-in-android. Or try using a custom adapter and change the typeface from adapter's getview() method.

Comment: Yes it is, I'm using it in another activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.layout.fragment_main,R.id.section_label, new String[]{
                getString(R.string.title_section1),
                getString(R.string.title_section2),
                getString(R.string.title_section3),
                "Acerca de...",
                }) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);          
        TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);             
        return v;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this method, I'll find out and tell you something, Thanks.

Comment: you just need to replace your setadapter code with my code,

Comment: Yes! Working perfectly! Thanks!