# Using otf type fonts in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts, webfonts

I see a lot of references for ttf fonts in Android studio but none describe usage of otf type fonts. Is there a way to use otf type fonts as well for Android studio projects?

Comment: check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426244/use-external-fonts-in-android. Also if u want to use otf font, try to convert them into ttf files, using online tool

Comment: You do not want to use fonts in Android Studio. Understand the difference.

Answer (score 21):

TTF is always been supported. OTF was later added at least in 1.6 and later, but partially.

```
Typeface face;

face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.otf");

textview.setTypeface(face);
```

Helpful link : [Use external fonts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426244/use-external-fonts-in-android)

You can convert this page : http://www.ehow.com/how_6192479_convert-dfont-ttf.html , https://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: This works! Just realized it is similar to ttf type usage. Just created an assets/fonts folder under src/main and added the otf file there and used the snippet above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add external fonts by adding it to the assets folder.

The [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) class specifies the typeface and intrinsic style of a font. This is used in the paint, along with optionally Paint settings like textSize, textSkewX, textScaleX to specify how text appears when drawn (and measured).

So create an object with reference to the font places in assets folder
and apply the font style by `setTypeface()` method.

Example:

```
TextView usernamesigin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username_signin_edittxt);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf");
usernamesigin.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K

Comment: in fragment or adapter you need `context.getAssets()`